# Objects visibility

Tags: android, view, visibility

I've done a lot of search but can't find the difference between `tools:visibility = "visible"` and `android:visibility = "visible"` ? Which situation I must use tools or android?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Here is the Simple Explanantion:**

`tools:visibility = "visible"` is used to manipulate view visibility on the IDE.It wont affect the view in the real time.It just used for Designing purpose in Android Studio

**while**

`android:visibility = "visible"` is the actual code which will be executed in run-time and will make changes to your views

Ref: http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes

Answer (score 11):

**tools:** attributes only contribute to design time preview while editing layouts while

**android:** actually affects how it will be displayed on actual device.

You can find further information [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) and [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes).

Answer (score 5):

The exactly question should be

> "What the difference between `android:...` and `tools:...` on Layout
>   XML files"

**tools** is one of the Design Attributes that can facilitate layout creation in XML in the development framework.This attribute is used to show the development framework what activity class is picked for implementing the layout. Using “tools:context”, Android Studio chooses the necessary theme for the preview automatically

**Android** is used in run-time app, when you launch your apk in a device

according to [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

If you see the [Design Time Layout Attributes](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes)

> The **tools** namespace is a specially recognized namespace by the Android tools, so all the attributes you define on view elements in the tools-namespace will be automatically stripped when the application is packaged and there is no runtime overhead.

So if we need to test something in layout editor only during development time which doesn't affect at runtime, we can use the `tools` namespace.

**Example:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First"
    tools:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

If the above layout is rendered in Android Studio designer view, first Button will be invisible. But at run time, it will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

TOOLS values will be used only in layout preview in Android Studio.t

ANDROID values will be used in app as normal.

So if you set values for main container:
tools:visibility:"gone"
android:visibility:"visible"

The main container in layout preview in AS will be gone, but if you launch app on emulator / device it will be visible.